# Trying to get the group name and version of my build.gradle dependencies in a custom gradle task

Tags: gradle, dependency-management, gradle-task

I'm trying to do something which I feel should be relatively straightforward but nothing on the internet seems to be giving me what I'm after.

Basically, I want to take the compile/testCompile dependencies from my `build.gradle` (I don't want any of the sub-dependencies - just literally as they are in the file), and for each one I want to do something with the group name, name and version. Let's just say I want to print them.

So here is my `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.spring.framework.cloud:spring-cloud-example:1.0.6'
    compile 'org.spring.framework.cloud:spring-cloud-other-example:1.1.6'
    testCompile 'org.spring.framework.cloud:spring-cloud-example-test:3.1.2'
}

task printDependencies {
    //some code in here to get results such as...
    // org.spring.framework.cloud  spring-cloud-other-example  1.1.6
}
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate over all you dependencies, you can itareate over all the configurations and the over all configuration dependencies. Like so:

```
task printDependencies {
    project.configurations.each { conf ->
        conf.dependencies.each { dep ->
            println "${dep.group}:${dep.name}:${dep.version}"
        }
    }
}
```

If you need exactly configuration dependencies, you can get them separately:

```
task printDependencies {
    project.configurations.getByName('compile') { conf ->
        conf.dependencies.each { dep ->
            println "${dep.group}:${dep.name}:${dep.version}"
        }
    }

    project.configurations.getByName('testCompile') { conf ->
        conf.dependencies.each { dep ->
            println "${dep.group}:${dep.name}:${dep.version}"
        }
    }
}
```

Or modify the first example, by adding condition to check `conf.name`

Comment: Brilliant - thanks Stanislav! And top marks for getting back so quickly too!